# Pandas Timestamp reformatting

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp

I have a pandas Timestamp column that looks like this:

`2021.11.04_23.03.33`

How do I convert this in a single liner to be able to look like this:

`2021-11-04 23:03:33`

Comment: Parse the string to datetime and convert back to string in the desired format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one does the trick:

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Timestamp'], format = '%Y.%m.%d_%H.%M.%S')
```

Answer (score 0):

use a regular expression by looking for the hour and minute second  pattern (\d{4})-\d{2}-(\d{2})\s+(\d{2})_(\d{2}).(\d{2}).(\d{2}) and use re.findall then get each group part then reassemble the datetime stringthen convert to a datetime

Comment: Why use a regex here? Just parse to datetime with a `format` specified

Comment: regex is one way, format may be another.   regular expression helps remove unwanted characters in the data and it handle more edge cases.